# Programatically configure NLog in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nlog

I recently download Nlog.dll from internet and add it into references part of project I'm writing code in C#. But even ready codes doesn't work in my simple console application. For the beginning I write it into my simple console application

[image]

As you can see here even some method of ondefined on other panel there is NLog classes located. How I can configure NLog from code?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

            var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = "file.txt" };
            var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("Hello World");

        }
    }
}
```

I get this error (in Russian language):

[image]

Comment: You are most probably missing a `using` statement, but could you post sample code as text instead of a screenshot? How to configure NLog programmatically is explained here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API (you probably followed this already)

Comment: yes I already followed it. The code is from there

Comment: Your sample code works for me. What error messages are you seeing? Does the code compile?

Comment: Did you install NLog via NuGet? Go to Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Package Manager Console and type `Install-Package NLog`

Comment: I'm running in VisualStudio 2012 the code dosn't compile in my machine

Comment: I download it from internet not from nuget. I only get  Nlog.dll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177861/discussion-between-jeroenh-and-jahongir-sabirov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct for the latest version of NLog on NuGet. The .dll you downloaded seems to be an older version of NLog.

Comment: .Net 4.5 version I think it should support it

Comment: How I can upgrade nuget version via Package Manager Console ?

Comment: I'm not sure as I don't have VS 2012 at hand, but maybe try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a85d0d0e-33e7-4f8e-b738-34d40b1f0de2/how-to-update-nuget-on-vs-2012

Comment: Also, in the future, please post the original error (in this case the problem with the nuget version) :-)

Comment: Thanks for advice my friend jeroenh :)